# Php upload file to server directory script

Tags: php

I was wondering if someone with more experience than me could take a quick second to have a look over my php script for uploading a file to my server.

I had a simple php script that uploaded my image the root of my server when I called the script in my code like so:

```
http://server.foo.com/images/uploadToDirectory.php
```

Now I'm trying to amend it so that I can put the name of a folder at the end with the following call:

```
 http://server.foo.com/images/uploadToDirectory.php?dir=test_folder
```

But for some reason my image is only getting sent to the root of the server. I've checked the logic of my c# code so I think it must be something to do with my php script. Could someone please have a look over it and tell me if I'm doing something silly with my code?

```
    <?
$_SESSION['directory'] = $_POST['directory'];
$uploaddir = './'.$_SESSION['directory'];
$file = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

print_r($_FILES);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "http://server.ip.address/images/{$file}";
}
else
{
    echo "Didn't Work!!!!";
    }

?>
```

Please note, I know this is probably a really bad way for me to go about doing what I want to do, but it's the way I've implemented it. My knowledge of PHP isn't very good.

For comparison here is the code to load to the root of the server:

```
    <?
$uploaddir = './';
$file = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

print_r($_FILES);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
       echo "http://server.ip.address/images/{$file}";
}
else
{
    echo "Didn't Work!!!!";
}
?>
```

Comment: if you are using a session, remember to do a session_start();  idk if this is your whole script, but i see the word session.

Comment: `$_POST['directory']` or `$_POST['dir']` ?

Comment: $_POST['dir']. But I have to tell you that YES this is a TERRIBLE way to do it and expect to get shell-scripted in no time, if not worse. It'll take someone a whole 2 minutes to take over your server with this.

Comment: $uploaddir = './'.$_SESSION['directory'];     so there is no string inside the directory array variable.  So it could be that your $_POST['directory'] is empty.  did you actually name your form input correctly directory?   check the value

Comment: I totally agree with cp510

Comment: Can just upload a php backdoor right away with that.  but for a trial and error test, to learn about uploads, you can do this, but just let it stay on localhost ;)

Comment: http://server.foo.com/images/uploadToDirectory.php?dir=test_folder   then its.. $_GET["dir"]

Comment: Yeah, this script is purely for my testing purposes. As I said my php knowledge just isn't there. If you can see why my file is auto uploading my root as opposed to the selected directory, I'd appreciate it if you could put up the few lines of code I'd need to change. I'll update with my original post to server php as well.

Comment: Ok good.  Change your post to a get method.  you are using url variables.  and directory to dir.  promice it wont go online ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so.. if you invoke your script like this:

```
http://server.foo.com/images/uploadToDirectory.php?dir=test_folder
```

Then your script should be:

```
$uploaddir = './'.$_GET["dir"];
```

That would collect your URL GET variable "dir".

Comment: read this aswell for a start :  http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/01/secure-file-upload-in-php-web-applications/